# T-SQL Replace date values in string

Tags: string, t-sql, replace

Can anyone recommend a method to replace or simply remove dates from a string? I was thinking something like; if string like `'%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%'` then replace that segment with NULL or '' but not sure of syntax. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Including example and expected outcome.
Here is an example of the string:

`HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to 4/24/09. TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative`

Would like to see something like this:
`HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to NULL. TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative`

Comment: Can you give us some examples of these strings that contain dates and your desired results.

Comment: Probably you should think doing this on client side using Regular expression and not touching the data itself. If you want to update the data itself, again you could think of using Regular Expressions. SQL server supports CLR and here is a link for a CLR RegEx addition to SQL server (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Following the comments by Ezequiel López Petrucci and Anthony Hancock, 
I came up with a better version.

To deal with the string format where the date might have one or two digits in it's month part, I've used a common table expression to change the single digit to two digits, and then replaced the entire thing with an empty string:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT STUFF(@string, PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', @string)+1, 1, '00') As string
)

SELECT STUFF(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', string), 8, '')
FROM CTE
```

To handle the multiple occurrences issue, I've linked together a couple of recursive common table expressions. This is a last resort kind of thing since it's probably going to have very poor performance:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT 1 as number, @string as string
    UNION ALL
    SELECT number+1, STUFF(string, PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', string)+1, 1, '00')
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE string LIKE '%[^0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%'
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) 1 as n, string
    FROM CTE1
    ORDER BY number DESC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1, STUFF(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', string), 8, '')
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE string LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%'
)

SELECT TOP 1 string
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY n DESC
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/IKDKX50333)

Use [`patindex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql) and [`stuff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql).
Patindex will return the index of the first pattern encountered in the string, and stuff will literally stuff a string into another, instead of whatever portion of the original string you specify:

Please note that it will only replace the first occurrence, as pointed out by Ezequiel López Petrucci in the comments.

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) =
'HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. 
 FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to 4/24/09. 
 TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  
 MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. 
 IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. 
 ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative'
```

The queries:

```
SELECT @string As Original

SELECT STUFF(@string, PATINDEX('%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', @string), 7, '') As Result
```

Results:

```
Original
HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. 
FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to 4/24/09. 
TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  
MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. 
IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. 
ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative

Result
HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. 
FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to . 
TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  
MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. 
IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. 
ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative
```

If you are dealing with multiple occurrences, and

Comment: This works for the first occurence. Will have to loop as long as there exists a PATINDEX.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci True, it only works for the first occurrence.

Comment: Doesn't it also only work for single digit months or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Yes. I was going by the sample data provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This should get what you need, not usually a fan of cursors and scalar functions but my brain wasn't working for an ITVF. It will catch any date variations between 7 and 10 characters in length. (Disclaimer: TRY_CONVERT requires SQL 2012 or higher)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateStrip (@inString NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outString NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@iterator INT = 1
    ;

    WHILE @iterator < LEN(@inString)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @dateLength TINYINT = 10;

        IF SUBSTRING(@inString,@iterator,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
        BEGIN

            WHILE @dateLength > 6
            BEGIN

                IF TRY_CONVERT(DATE,SUBSTRING(@inString,@iterator,@dateLength)) IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    SET @inString = STUFF(@inString,@iterator,@dateLength,'');
                    BREAK;
                END

                SET @dateLength -= 1;
            END
        END

        SET @iterator += 1;
    END

    RETURN @inString
END
GO

DECLARE @inString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to 4/24/2009. TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative 10/12/2019';

SELECT dbo.DateStrip(@inString);
```

Comment: While this might be a better solution then mine, please note that `try_convert` was introduced in 2012, so it will not work for older versions (2008 is still supported by Microsoft)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I thought about that when writing this, I know some people are still stuck on 2008 R2. I'll add a disclaimer in the description.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use patternSplitCM for this.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(8000) = 
'HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to 4/24/09. TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative';
SELECT (
  SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN [Matched] = 0 THEN Item
        WHEN [Matched] = 1 AND Item NOT LIKE '%[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]' THEN Item
        ELSE 'NULL'
    END +''
  FROM dbo.patternSplitCM(@string, '[0-9/]')
  ORDER BY itemNumber
  FOR XML PATH(''));
```

Results:

```
HISTORY: Patient is seen for screening. FILMS COMPARED: Comparison is made with prior exams dating back to NULL. TECHNIQUE: The following mammographic views were obtained: bilateral craniocaudal and  bilateral mediolateral oblique.  MAMMOGRAM FINDINGS: The breasts are heterogeneously dense.  This may lower the sensitivity of  mammography. There are no masses, asymmetries, or suspicious calcifications. IMPRESSION / RECOMMENDATION: There is no mammographic evidence of malignancy. Routine follow-up mammogram in 1 year is recommended. ASSESSMENT:  BI-RADS Category 1:  Negative
```